# How can I run this python script on all html files under a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, python

I have a python script

```
$ cat ~/script.py
import sys
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse
doc = parse(sys.argv[1])
title = doc.find('//title')
title.text = span2.text.strip()
print etree.tostring(doc)
```

I can run the script on an individual file by issuing something like

```
$ python script.py foo.html > new-foo.html
```

My problem is that I have a directory `~/webpage` that contains hundreds of `.html` files scattered throughout sub-directories. I would like to run `~/script.py` on all of these html files. How can I do this?

I'm aware that I can list all the `.html` files under `~/webpage/` by issuing

```
$ find ~/webpage/ -name "*.html"
```

but I'm not quite sure how to use this list to run my script on them.

Comment: Python can walk a directory no problem, check out `os.walk()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try a for loop to iterate through the files in the directory:

`for f in *.html; do python script.py f > new-"$f".html; done`

Comment: This will cause every iteration of the loop to overwrite `new-foo.html`. Should be `... > new-"$f".html`.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-exec` command of `find`

```
find ~/webpage/ -name "*.html" -exec sh -c 'python script.py {} > new-{}' \;
```

For some versions, you might need to do

```
find ~/webpage/ -name "*.html" -exec sh -c 'python script.py $0 > new-$0' {} \;
```

Comment: Double check before you run this that it actually works as expected.  I believe some versions of `find` require `{}` to be a single arg, or they won't expand it.